# Assign values to every array result in foreach

Tags: php, mysql, arrays, multidimensional-array

I have counted with PHP and MySql query all cookies of specific tastes for an array of cookies. Query returns amount of cookies for each taste. It returns just numbers as if I do **->fetch()** there are unnecessary nests of arrays.

Here is the code:

```
$cookies = array();
$cookies[] = 'Chocolate';
$cookies[] = 'Vanilla';
$cookies[] = 'Stracciatella';

$results = [];
foreach ($cookies as $cookie) {
    $results[] = $this->getEntityManager()->getConnection()->executeQuery(
        "SELECT COUNT(*) FROM sweets WHERE cookies LIKE :cookies",
        ['cookies' => '%"' . $cookie . '"%']
    )->fetchColumn();
}
```

Here I got te result like :

```
 [
    8,
    4,
    1
 ]
```

Now, I want to assign every of that value to it cookie so I can get clean array key name and result like:

This would be desired output:

```
array('Chocolate' => '8', 'Vanilla' => '4', 'Stracciatella' => '1');
```

So I tried somethnig like:

```
  $cookieCount = [];
    foreach ($results as $key => $value) {
        $cookieCount['Chocolate'] = $value;
        $cookieCount['Vanilla'] = $value;
        $cookieCount['Stracciatella'] = $value;
    }

    return $cookieCount;
```

Can someone help? Thanks

Comment: `$results[$cookie] = ...`

Comment: "Notice: Undefined index: Chocolate" @raina77ow

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You mistake the key, it should be :

```
    $cookieCount = [];
    foreach ($results as $key => $value) {
        $roleCount[$cookie] = $value;
    }

    return $cookieCount; // or $roleCount ?
```

Comment: Thank you, this does it! But it's not returning values where count is 0 ? @Lounis

Answer (score 1):

```
foreach ($cookies as $cookie) {
    // Set a key here
    $results[$cookie] = $this->getEntityManager()->getConnection()->executeQuery(
        "SELECT COUNT(*) FROM sweets WHERE cookies LIKE :cookies",
        ['cookies' => '%"' . $cookie . '"%']
    )->fetchColumn();
}
```

And iteration `foreach ($results as $key => $value)` is not required.

Comment: Thank you for replay but it returns it just the same. its: [8, 4, 1]  @u_mulder

Comment: @gisem1990 you don't understand what you are doing, value are [8, 4 ,1] but keys are ['Chocolate', 'Vanilla', 'Stracciatella', ...] , try var_dump() to see.

Comment: What shows `print_r($results)` __right after__ `foreach`?

Answer (score 0):

You can do this in a slightly different way and accomplish what you want with one query instead of one for each cookie:

```
$sql = 'SELECT cookies, count(*) as cnt FROM sweets GROUP BY cookies';
$queryResults = $this->getEntityManager()->getConnection()->executeQuery($sql)->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
$results = [];
foreach ($queryResults as $queryResult) {
    $results[$queryResult['cookies']] = $queryResult['cnt'];
}
```

(I wasn't sure which DBAL you are using so line 3 may be incorrect, but basically you want to fetch all as an associative array)

This approach also means that any value for "cookies" in the database will automatically be returned without changing your PHP code

Comment: "Notice: Undefined index: cookies" @Matt Thanks for replay. :)

Comment: As I said it's probably to do with line 3. I don't know what DBAL you are using so not sure what fn you need to call to get assoc results

Answer (score 0):

Simply you can do `$cookieCount[$cookies[$key]] = $results[$key];`

See as below:

```
$cookies = array();
$cookies[] = 'Chocolate';
$cookies[] = 'Vanilla';
$cookies[] = 'Stracciatella';

$results =  [
    8,
    4,
    1
 ];
 
  $cookieCount = [];
  foreach ($results as $key => $value) {
      $cookieCount[$cookies[$key]] = $results[$key];
  }

    
  return $cookieCount;
```

output will be:

> Array (
> [Chocolate] => 8
> [Vanilla] => 4
> [Stracciatella] => 1 )

Comment: Thank you for replay but it returns it just the same. its: [8, 4, 1] @DevsiOdedra

Comment: @gisem1990 which type of output you want?

Comment: "Notice: Undefined index: Chocolate" if ->fetch()  @DevsiOdedra

Comment: @gisem1990 visit http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/8afe09f39132c911c8f06fd1d3744d60b3c58a3a